# Get result like Tree mysql

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Hello i have some code here

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT   `categories`.`category_name` ,  `categories`.`id`, `subcategories`.`subcategory_name`, `subcategories`.`sub_id` 
FROM  `categories`  
LEFT JOIN  `subcategories` ON  `categories`.`id` =  `subcategories`.`category_id` ORDER BY category_name ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['category_name'];
$sub_name = $row['subcategory_name'];
echo "id--->",$id, " - ", $name, " ---> ", $sub_name, "<br />" ;
}
```

And my result is this
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Οργανα Γυμναστικής
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Water Sports 
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Πολεμικές Τέχνες
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Ιππασία - Ιππικοί Όμιλοι
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Tennis Clubs
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Αθλητικά Έπαθλα
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Γήπεδα 5χ5 - Mundialito
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Χιονοδρομικά Κέντρα
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> PaintBall - Χρωματοσφαίριση
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Fitness Clubs - Γυμναστήρια
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Αναρριχητικά Πεδία
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Ποδήλατα
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Αθλητικά Είδη
id--->1 - Αθλητισμός ---> Golf Clubs - Γήπεδα Γκολφ

how can i make that my result show like this

  Αθλητισμός

Οργανα Γυμναστικής

Water Sports

Πολεμικές Τέχνες

Comment: use unorder list <ul></ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
echo '<ul>';

$categoryName = FALSE;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

  $id = $row['id'];
  $name = $row['category_name'];
  $sub_name = $row['subcategory_name'];

  if ( $categoryName != $name) {
     echo "$name";
  }

  echo "<li>$sub_name</li>";

  $categoryName = $name;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: but i want to have like categories and subcategories, because i have a 30  cagetgories and more then 100 subcategories

Comment: print your category in while loop

Comment: haw can i do that my friend?